# jQuery UI sortable div with overflow: auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two sortable columns that placed on div with fixed height and `overflow: auto`.

When I try to move last item from left column to the right column I need to scroll all the way down, take the item and scroll with him up. When I came up to the first item in right column, I cannot drop my item there until I hovering him on left column items.

I'm feeling that somehow a focus of an item that I drag is going and he returns when I'm passing over his original column.

Any ideas?

[Here is JSFiddle with an example](http://jsfiddle.net/dima_k/aes85/)

The issue is happening when you drag an item straight to the right column and not when you drag him over left column. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. Do you want to be able to drag an item for the left column to the right column without scrolling all the way to the top?

If that is the case, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/aes85/1/

```
#wrapper{
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#List1, #List2
{
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    border: solid 2px black;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 50px; /* <--added this */
}
```

I just added padding of *50px* to both columns so you have *space* available to drop an item without hovering over existing items. When one column is empty, you will still have a "space" to drop an item in.

To solve the scrolling back up problem, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/aes85/2/.

```
#wrapper{
    height: 470px; /* <-- changed this to 470px */
    overflow: auto;
}

#List1, #List2
{
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    border: solid 2px black;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height:100%; /* <-- added 100% height */
}
```

Here I just set the heights of both columns to *470px*. This is tall enough to hold all items in one column without any overflow issues. Just remember to adjust the height of the columns to handle having one column hold all the items. Also, when one column is empty, the column's height still remains at *470px* and you can drag an item into the empty column without scrolling up.

Comment: Thanks for the answering, but first one is not my case. I always have a placeholder, it's not a problem. The second one isn't help me because I can't play with a height of wrapper. The items are dynamically added to the list, so I can't fetch the height for all scenarios.

Comment: what if you dynamically set the height of the wrapper when a new item is added to a column?

Comment: No, the height is calculated dynamically with some logic. I can't play with it.